# No project template for a ‘WPF Ribbon Application’

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, ribbon

I am unable to get a WPF Ribbon project to show in Visual Studio. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/019837dd-d439-4028-9acb-924f9588d2de/) is a link to a thread for someone that had an issue in Visual Studio 2010.

I have tried everything suggested there but to no avail.

I have Visual Studio 2012 Express for Desktop installed but nothing is showing up. I have tried uninstalling and re-installing but no luck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A simple work around would be to simply replace `<Window>` with `<RibbonWindow>` and `<Ribbon>` as the first child. Keep in mind that the [Ribbon control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is already integrated into .NET 4.5.

First edit your `MainWindow.xaml` by replacing `Window` with `RibbonWindow` and add `<Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" Title="Ribbon Title">`.

**Example:**

```
<RibbonWindow x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

        Title="MainWindow"
        x:Name="RibbonWindow"
        Width="640" Height="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" Title="Ribbon Title">
            ...........
        </Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

You will also need to edit the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` to inherit the `RibbonWindow` class instead of `Window`.

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
```

Last remember to import the reference from the .NET Framework.

```
System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon
```

**Edit:** *Update with solution for `VB.Net`.*

1) Add reference

- Right click on your project and choose `Add Reference`.
- Find `System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon` under Assemblies and Framework.
- Click `OK` to save.

2) Edit your `MainWindow.xaml`

- Back up any existing code.
- Replace the default template with the code in my Example.
- Add your new content within the `<Ribbon></Ribbon>` tag.

3) Edit your `Mainwindow.xaml.vb`

- Right click on `MainWindow.xaml` and click `View Code`.
- Change `Class Window` to `Class RibbonWindow`.

4) Run the program!

Comment: Thanks for the response. Not to sound naive but where exactly do I place this XML in regards to a new project?

Comment: You can edit your existing project. Updating the code slightly give me a few seconds.

Comment: To make it clear you simply edit the existing files mentioned in my post in your new project.

Comment: @JamesBrunet The code got cut short earlier, updated it *again*. :D

Comment: Thanks again. I am using VB BTW. It is not recognising RibbonWindow. But that is probably because I have no idea what to do with System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon or how to inherit in VB.

Comment: My bad. It should be pretty much the same. I'll see if I can update my answer.

Comment: It's not your bad at all. You've been extremely helpful.

Comment: The ribbon was covering the title bar when I use RibboWindow. I used your xaml piece and it fixed the problem. I don't know how, I couldn't notice any reasonable cause.